# Eldritch Horror test resolutions in other board games

Tags: arkham-horror, dice, eldritch-horror

I'm new at modern board-games, basically, and I got Eldritch Horror as a present.

I love the test resolution system where you through n number of dice and the number of 5 or 6 determines if a test is passed or failed.

Is their any other board game that use exactly this system (by exactly, I mean throughing **n** dice, then counting the number of **5 or 6**)? Does Arkham horror use the same system for instance?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a list of games with a feature

Comment: Arkham Horror does in fact use the same pass/fail system of 5-6 pass, 1-4 fail.

Comment: There is a close vote option labelled *"Game recommendation questions are off topic [...]"*. I'm not sure how this question deviates from that template such that it requires a custom reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello and welcome to the world of modern board games. The mechanism you are talking about is a common mechanism for a number of board games.

You are correct that [Arkham Horror](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/15987/arkham-horror) uses this exact mechanism.

Other games use a similar mechanism:

- [Summoner Wars](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/93260/summoner-wars-master-set) - uses a 6 sided die for combat but here you typically hit on a 3+
- [Eclipse](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/72125/eclipse) - uses a 6 sided die for combat but here you initially only hit on a 6

I'm quite positive there are dozens more that could be listed, but those were the first games that came to mind that I was familiar with.

Comment: Betrayal (at House on the Hill) has modified dice with two blank faces, two 1's and two 2's. This is equivalent to rolling a d6 where a 3 or 4 counts as a success, and a 5 or 6 counts as two successes.